# Simple MySQL UPDATE query - very low performance

Tags: mysql, performance

A simple mysql update query is very slow sometimes. Here is the query:

```
update produse 
set vizite = '135' 
where id = '71238'
```

My simplified table structure is:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `produse`  
(
  `id` int(9) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `nume` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `vizite` int(9) NOT NULL default '1',

  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  KEY `vizite` (`vizite`),
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=945179 ;
```

I use MySQL 5.0.77 and the table is MyISAM.

The table is about 752.6 MO and has 642,442 for the moment.

The database runs on a dedicated VPS that has 3Gb of RAM and 4 processors of 2G each. There are no more than 6-7 queries of that type per second when we have high traffic, but the query is slow not only then.

Comment: Have you looked at the query plan to check that it is doing what you think it is?

Comment: It won't make a difference, but there is no need to use quotes for id while your id is int: where id=71238

Comment: FYI: You can see details about what keys are being used by using [MySQL's `explain`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html). Try this: `explain update produse set vizite='135' where id='71238';`

Comment: And question: do you have some numbers for "very slow"? What is the performance you get and what is the performance you expect?

Comment: thank you for the hint. I updated my code and I can't expect to see the result. As an observation, I get an error if I try the explain update produse set vizite='135' where id='71238' query: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'update produse set vizite=38 where id=435385' at line 1

Comment: The update query take as long as 5-6 seconds sometimes.

Comment: how many selects do you have on that table and what kind of selects do you have?

Answer (score 0):

First, try rebuilding your indexes, it might happen that query is not using them (you can see that using EXPLAIN statement with your update query).

Another possibility is that you have many selects on that table or long running selects, which causes long locks. You can try using replication and have your select queries executed on slave database, only, and updates on master, only. That way, you will avoid table locks caused by updates while you are doing selects and vice versa.